# Redirection failing if |& is used instead of | (pipe) - bash bug?

Tags: bash, redirection

This is an artificial minimized example of successfully throwing `stdout` away and piping `stderr` to the next command by redirecting it to `stdout`:

```
strace echo something 2>&1 >/dev/null | wc -l
38
```

Changing the pipe operator to the include-stderr-version `|&` fails unexpectedly, I suspect because of the wrong order of redirection operations in the calling `bash`:

```
strace echo something 2>&1 >/dev/null |& wc -l
0
```

Workaround is to use a subshell:

```
(strace echo something 2>&1 >/dev/null) |& wc -l
38
```

**Is that a bash bug or is it some useful bash feature ?**

My expectation would be that the pipe is setup and connected to `stdout` first and, if the `|&` operator is used, `dup`ed to `stderr` second, and then the command's "inner" redirections applied over the "outer" pipe last.

While `man bash` explicitly states the "implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by the command", this seems wrong as it is something else than what is documented the sentence before: "If `|&` is used, command's standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2's standard input through the pipe", which does in fact only happen in the absence of any further redirections.

Answer (score 2):

#### tl;dr

Not a bug. `|&` is like an alias for `2>&1 |`, a shorthand, a way to type less. Note `2>&1` is now the final redirection in this part of the pipeline. That's all.

---

#### Analysis

The following citation is quite clear to me. You need to read the whole of it. In the question you cited few sentences without the broader context.

> The output of each command in the pipeline is connected via a pipe to the input of the next command. That is, each command reads the previous command’s output. This connection is performed before any redirections specified by the command.
>
> If `|&` is used, command1’s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2’s standard input through the pipe; **it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`**. This implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by the command.

<sup>(emphasis mine, [source link](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines))</sup>

Take `foo … |& bar`, where `…` denotes redirections specified by the command. `|&` is a shorthand (think: "alias") for `2>&1 |`, so the command is like `foo … 2>&1 | bar`; and the `foo` part is like

```
foo >fifo … 2>&1
```

where `>fifo` denotes the connection to the stdin of `bar` (I used the name `fifo` but in fact it's an anonymous pipe).

There is no deeper philosophy, `|&` simply "expands" to `2>&1 |`. Then `|` behaves like `>fifo` *before* `…` ("this connection is performed before any redirections specified by the command") and `2>&1` stays *at the end* ("this implicit redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed after any redirections specified by the command"). In general redirections are performed from left to right, so  `>fifo … 2>&1` is a good representation of what happens.

---

#### Example: your command

Your command:

```
strace echo something 2>&1 >/dev/null |& wc -l
```

"expands" to:

```
strace echo something 2>&1 >/dev/null 2>&1 | wc -l
```

and the `strace` part behaves like:

```
strace echo something >fifo 2>&1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

where `>/dev/null 2>&1` redirects the stdout to `/dev/null` and then stderr to what stdout is now, so also to `/dev/null`. It doesn't matter at all where the stdout and stderr pointed to just before `>/dev/null 2>&1`; this particular snippet does not depend on previous redirections.

---

#### Example: your workaround

Your workaround is:

```
(strace echo something 2>&1 >/dev/null) |& wc -l
```

which "expands" to:

```
(strace echo something 2>&1 >/dev/null) 2>&1 | wc -l
```

and the first part is like:

```
(strace echo something 2>&1 >/dev/null) >fifo 2>&1
```

Note it's different than `>fifo 2>&1 >/dev/null 2>&1` we observed in the allegedly failing case.

For completeness let's analyze how `(foo 2>&1 >/dev/null) >fifo 2>&1` works:

1. First a subshell is created, its stdin gets redirected to the fifo (`>fifo`), its stderr gets redirected to the current stdout (the last `2>&1`), so to the fifo as well.
2. Then `foo` is about to run inside the subshell. Without further redirections it would inherit the standard descriptors from the subshell. This means the "default" stdout and stderr of `foo` both go to the fifo.
3. Stderr of `foo` gets redirected to its current stdout (the first `2>&1`). They are both the fifo, so this changes nothing. Then stdout of `foo` gets redirected to `/dev/null` (`>/dev/null`).

In effect stderr (but not stdout) of `foo` goes to the fifo, i.e. through the pipe.

---

#### Conclusions

The whole issue is not "redirection failing", it's not a bug. It's simply because `|&` turns into `2>&1 |`, but then `|` acts *before* and `2>&1` acts *after* any explicit redirections you specify.

Do not consider `|&` as "`|` with extra functionality". When using it, think of an alias, a textual replacement: imagine `|&` will expand to `2>&1 |` (as if you *typed* `2>&1 |` instead of `|&`); then `2>&1` and `|` will do their respective jobs independently (as if `|&` was never a thing).

Comment: So you explained the observed behavior but did not answer the question whether this  is actually some useful bash feature. If the current behavior is in no case useful, it should be treated as a bug and changed to that of the workaround because this is advantageous and would not break existing scripts.

Comment: @Juergen It is useful because you can type less, *if you know what you're doing*.